# How can I define a type that allows keys of nested properties

Tags: typescript

I have an model with several properties, each of them are sub models:

ex:

```
const myModel = {
  a : { x: 'foo' },
  b : { y: 'bar' }
}
```

I would like to have a correct type for `function read(model, level1Key, level2Key) {}` which will fail type check if `level1Key` and `level2Key` are not matching.
ex:
`read(myModel, 'a', 'x') // OK, returns 'foo'`
`read(myModel, 'b', 'y') // OK, returns 'bar'`
`read(myModel, 'a', 'y') // NOT OK, typescript will fail`

```js
type ConferenceLocation = {
  address: string;
  city: string;
  zip: number;
  state: string;
};

type ConferenceDescription = {
  name: string;
  from: string;
  to: string;
};

type Conference = {
  description: ConferenceDescription;
  location: ConferenceLocation;
};

const conference: Conference = {
  description: {
    name: "CES - Las Vegas 2020",
    from: "2020-01-07T00:00:00Z",
    to: "2020-01-10T00:00:00Z"
  },
  location: {
    address: "3150 Paradise Rd",
    city: "Las Vegas",
    zip: 89109,
    state: "NV"
  }
};

function read(
  conference: Conference,
  property: keyof Conference,
  key: string
): void {
  document.writeln(
    conference && conference[property] && conference[property][key]
  );
  document.writeln("<br />");
}

read(conference, "description", "name");
read(conference, "location", "city");
read(conference, "description", "city");
read(conference, "meta", "city");
```

As we can see here: https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-wave-z9s1w

The transpiler is raising an error for `read(conference, "meta", "city");` because `"meta"` is not a valid `keyof Conference`

But as I defined the parameter `key`as a `string`, it allows `read(conference, "description", "city");`, which will fail at runtime.

Any idea how to achieve this? Or is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a bit surprised to see nobody's suggested using a [generic function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) with [`keyof` and lookup types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#keyof-and-lookup-types).  I won't constrain `conference` to type `Conference` (since the `myModel` example won't work if I do):

```
function read<C, K extends keyof C>(
  conference: C,
  property: K,
  key: keyof C[K]
): void {
  document.writeln(
    String(conference && conference[property] && conference[property][key])
  );
  document.writeln("<br />");
}
```

Note that the function is generic in `C`, the type of `conference`, and `K`, the type of `property`.  The type `K` is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) to be assignable to `keyof C`, and the type of `key` is required to be `keyof C[K]`, meaning that it must be one of the keys of the `K`-keyed property of the type `C`... or that it must be one of the keys of the type of `conference[property]`.

Also note that I converted the `writeln` argument to a `string` (using `String()`) since `writeln` call signature requires a `string` and the compiler can't guarantee that `conference[property][key]` is one.

---

So, does it work?

```
read(myModel, 'a', 'x') // OK
read(myModel, 'b', 'y') // OK
read(myModel, 'a', 'y') // error! "y" is bad

read(conference, "description", "name"); // okay
read(conference, "location", "city"); // okay
read(conference, "description", "city"); // error! "city" is bad
read(conference, "meta", "city"); // error! "meta" is bad
```

Looks like it.  Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-P9nQAcgIPD8I9PDi3vO8oAAeRdegMKw79f3PfCdCIqA8JAUjyKomj0IgFh6Jwpi2MI-COLIu8KLQGJUAAQkZEAoP5KAkOYV9eP4gcJ2dXZlnKHxOk+RltggJ8RC4uA-QIEBaL4zDNLqbTyQ6RBDN2SRQFM8zLOs9S7PHBzGV01YXO09yFL3LipLgWTGTCxTrhUmyNP8lxtJCYACFcuKIok91UGkuTdnSzKoCUxK6DUoA)

Comment: I just found out about conditional typing with `extends` this morning :) This looks great!

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you're asking the Typescript compiler to "dig too deeply" into your code to find problems. It's not a totally unreasonable expectation, but it's a little more than Typescript can handle.

Consider your failing example:

```
read(conference, "meta", "city");
```

In this case, Typescript can easily determine that `meta` is not valid because it is not in `keyof Conference`. This is straight-forward because it's clearly defined.

But in the other example:

```
read(conference, "description", "city");
```

you might expect it to look at the type of `conference.description` and see that the `city` property is not set.

But in order to do this, it would require that it evaluate `conference[property]` to determine the type of that value and then check to see if the property denoted by `key` is present. Unfortunately, it cannot do that because `property` is not known before runtime.

"But," you say. "The value *is* known - it's specified right there in code as a constant."

This is true, but it comes down to this line of code:

```
document.writeln(
    conference && conference[property] && conference[property][key]
);
```

and in order to determine the type of `conference[property]`, Typescript would need to **execute** this code. And that is something that Typescript does not do - it is a tool for *static code analysis*.

Comment: The type system is able to handle nested property lookup types without resorting to executing the code.  See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57683912/2887218) for more details

Answer (score 0):

You can use Typescript function overloading to accomplish your goal. Overloads are processed in order until a successful check is made. To provide type checking for your methods, I would suggest the following:

```
function read(
  conference: Conference,
  property: "description",
  key: keyof ConferenceDescription
): void;

function read(
  conference: Conference,
  property: "location",
  key: keyof ConferenceLocation
): void;

function read(
  conference: Conference,
  property: "location" | "description",
  key: keyof ConferenceDescription | keyof ConferenceLocation): void {
    document.writeln(
      conference && conference[property] && conference[property][key]
    );
    document.writeln("<br />");
}

read(conference, "description", "name"); //OK
read(conference, "location", "city");    //OK
read(conference, "description", "city"); //BAD
read(conference, "meta", "city");        //BAD
```

Comment: This works, but it is not really generic, which was the purpose of the read function (i.e. deep read of any 2 level models).
With your solution, I have to adapt the type of `key` every time a new property is added to the model